# bash: javac: command not found [Sublime Text 3]

Tags: java, sublimetext3

Recently I was trying to switch from Eclipse to Sublime Text 3 to program some Java stuff. But not like Eclipse, in SL3 you have to configure the Build System for building program. The problem is when I was trying to run a simple Java program:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

the text editor gave me this message:

```
bash: javac: command not found
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: javac "/home/newbie/Projects/Test/Testing.java" && java "Testing"]
[dir: /home/newbie/Projects/Test]
[path: /app/utils/bin:/app/sublime_merge/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin]
```

I did download the JDK on the machine but somehow the text editor couldn't find javac (perhaps also java). I wonder what happens with my Java Build System:

```
{
   "shell_cmd": "javac \"$file\" && java \"$file_base_name\"",
   "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.java",
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me out with this, especially during the quaratine time. Also, I'm using Linux Mint 19.3.

Comment: How did you download the JDK? Where did you install it? I would assume the message is correct, and that sublime can't find your JDK (at least not in the path you have specified).

Comment: I downloaded it by the command line "sudo apt-get install default-jdk". I still can run the Java program on the terminal by using javac and java but not in the SL3.

Comment: We're getting warmer.... on the terminal, type `which java`. That will tell you what you need to add to your path. You need the directory where `java` is. Not `java` on the end. And that should be that.

Comment: The terminal gave me `/usr/bin/java`. Do I need to add the `path` having that directory path in my Build System?

Comment: Actually that looks fine. You have `/usr/bin` - what about `which javac`? I think the actual installation is probably under `/usr/share/java/` but the symlinks should work. Maybe someone else will have an idea. Or you could try a real IDE (eclipse, intellij, netbeans) - there are lots of choices. I registered Sublime (paid my own money for it), and I still use an IDE for java. Because it's a fantastic text editor. But not a great IDE.

Comment: The javac is also in the same directory with java which within `/usr/bin`. But if that can't be done then it's fine. The reason I switch over SL3 is its lightweight characteristic that fit my old laptop.

Comment: It's a text editor. It's a very good text editor. And it can be made to work. But really your question is "how do I make sublime work" not "how do I solve this programming problem". So it's not a great fit for StackOverflow in general. But, it is at least programming related. Anyway, you need to do more configuration/setup. You can try setting a `JAVA_HOME` variable to the **correct** subfolder of `/usr/share/java` (which I can't tell you what it is from here). But until you get that done, it won't work. And the way to do it can be inscrutable. Try searching with google. Be patient.

Comment: Use something else until someone offers a better suggestion. BTW, xubuntu or lubuntu (or even debian) would probably be better for an older laptop. LinuxMint is **not** lightweight. At all. Unless you're comparing it to Windows.

Comment: Can you compile the file and run it from the command line? i.e. `javac Test.java` and then `java Test`. I'm running Linux Mint 17 and installed the `default-jdk` package to try and help. Building your hello world program worked file with the default `JavaC.sublime-build` file and also with the one you posted, which simply adds ` && java \"$file_base_name\"` to the `shell_cmd` and so runs the hello world code after compiling it.

Comment: I still can run the program on the terminal or other IDE, I think the main problem is SL3 cannot find `javac` and `java` file.

Comment: It's very odd, I suggest trying the full path to `javac` and `java` in the `shell_cmd`. Here is a link to a `JavaC.sublime-build` file containing alternatives for you to try: [JavaC.sublime-build Gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/mattst/7b50925fb9f00f56476276fe2cf21049). You'll need to comment out all but the entry you are trying.

Comment: I tried your solution but it's still not working. The first one still gives me the same result, the other two with full path give me `bash: /usr/bin/javac: No such file or directory` which is weird, since I run `which java` and `which javac` they are indeed within that directory.

Comment: @QuânTrần I mentioned this (briefly). `/usr/bin/java` and `/usr/bin/javac` (on Linux Mint), are symlinks. From the [Mint Forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=300700), *The standard advise is setting the needed environment variables up in e.g. /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh,
`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_221`
`export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`
... Log your user out and back in or reboot after adding the file.* (You may need to adjust that JAVA_HOME, look at the contents of /usr/lib/jvm and modify as appropriate)

Comment: Even with all those changes, my SL3 still can't recognize where are `javac` and `java`. I even had to reinstall the JDK and set the path manually...I barely have any clue.